# Scientific Word LaTeX editor + MacKichan going out of business

Tags: wysiwyg, scientific-workplace

It appears that MacKichan, the company behind the Scientific Word LaTeX editor, is going out of business (source: https://www.mackichan.com/)

As a number of people using this software might be in this forum (there certainly have been questions about it in the past), I wonder whether somebody has looked into what the closest alternative software could be, with a focus on making the transition as seamless as possible?

Do people have some pro/cons comparisons? I had looked into this question a few years back, but back then I had had the impression that Scientific Word (at least in Version 5.5) outclassed all other WYSIWYG editors *easily*. At any rate I don't think the appearance of a better software can possibly have been the reason for the shutdown, if anything completely redeveloping Version 6 was a mistake.

The webpage says "We expect to make Scientific Word an open source product eventually." which would be great, but just in case this ultimately won't happen, I think the above questions have some relevance.

Does anyone know more about this transition-to-open source process?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an objective answer here: 'use an editor you like' is about it.

Comment: Oh the 'we will make it open source' business - whilst it's off-topic for an answer, it's commercial software so they own the copyright and can do whatever they like basically with no notice

Comment: Also, even if they make it open source, somebody should step in to maintain it --- I suppose it will be a considerable amount of code.

Comment: "In time, the source will be posted on Github." I guess work on Scientific Word will continue in the Open-Source community

Answer (score 1):

The open source version of Scientific Word is out, but they aren't making Scientific Workplace open-source.  A friend of mine who uses Apple has been using SWP on a VMWare Fusion emulation software for years (it emulates Windows on Apple), and when he upgrades to a new computer he just moves the virtual machine directly over to his new computer, without reinstalling Scientific Workplace.