# What is a shortcut for "save file" in Scientific Word 5.5?

Tags: scientific-workplace

This is about scientific word editor ([Scientific Word LaTeX editor + MacKichan going out of business](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603188/scientific-word-latex-editor-mackichan-going-out-of-business))

I would like to understand whether a user can create a keyboard shortcut for SW5.5

In particular I would like to understand whether there is a keyboard shortcut for "saving a file".

I have checked the documentation at https://www.sciword.co.uk/manuals/GetStarted-55.pdf but could not find one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, welcome. I don't know who flagged this, but I don't think it's hard to understand what you're asking, so feel free to ignore the above comment.