# Why does Scientific Workplace 5.5 not work with Windows 11?

Tags: windows, scientific-workplace

I installed Scientific Workplace 5.5 in both Windows 10 and 11. There were no troubles during installation. Once installed, the software runs smoothly on Windows 10, but in Windows 11 it does not start at all (no error message).

Does anyone else have the same problem?

Note: I also tried Scientific Word and Scientific Workplace 6 on Windows 11. They work correctly. Scientific Workplace 5.5 is the only one I cannot get to run.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136316/discussion-on-question-by-jesus-garcia-why-scientific-workplace-5-5-does-not-run).

Comment: I am afraid there is no support now for SW. Try asking at some microsoft forum.  But this is one more reason for me never to upgrade to windows 11. You could always install Virtual box on your windows 11, install windows 10 in it, and then install SW there to use it if you only have one PC.

Comment: Should your text be interpreted as you can install it but not start swp? Have you tried starting swp from the command line? Just to see if it gives messages at the start that are usually lost when we start from a menu or double clicking a file.

Answer (score 1):

I am still using Windows 7 and 8.1. Hence, I am not sure whether the information below will help.

That being said, I think that there is a chance that the combination of the two steps below may solve the problem.
(1) Install SW with Windows running in safe mode.
(2) Run SW using "Windows 7 compatibility".

Since you have already installed SW, then first try just step (2). To run a program in the compatibility mode, right click in the corresponding *exe* file (or in a shortcut to the program). Next, go to the compatibility button. If (2) alone does not do the trick, then you may wish to uninstall SW and then install it back in safe mode.

The source for the suggestion is [www.sciword.co.uk](http://www.sciword.co.uk) (UK distributor of SW). The links below may help.

https://www.sciword.co.uk/mailings/June2016.htm

https://www.sciword.co.uk/mailings/May2022.htm

https://www.sciword.co.uk/mailings/circulars.htm

Please, if that works out for you, then let us know. I am interested in this question because I am about to get a new computer. Hence, most likely I need to migrate to Windows 11.

**Update**:
Given the answer by Nasser at [Scientific Word LaTeX editor + MacKichan going out of business](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603188/scientific-word-latex-editor-mackichan-going-out-of-business), it seems that instead of step (1) it may be better to use the following:

(1') Install SW with Windows running in *safe mode with networking*.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Scientific Workplace 5.5 is not fully compatible with Windows 11. You could try checking the software developer's website or support forums to see if there are any known issues with running the software on Windows 11.

You could also try running the software in compatibility mode, which can sometimes help to resolve compatibility issues. To do this, right-click on the Scientific Workplace 5.5 icon and select Properties. In the Properties window, go to the Compatibility tab and check the box next to "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and select a previous version of Windows, such as Windows 10. Then, try running the software again to see if it works.

If compatibility mode does not work, you could also try running the software as an administrator. Right-click on the Scientific Workplace 5.5 icon and select "Run as administrator" to launch the software with elevated privileges.

If none of these solutions work, you may need to contact the software developer or technical support team for further assistance. They may be able to provide more specific guidance on how to get the software running on Windows 11.